# Column names with space breaks filtering

Tags: jqgrid

I have a colmodel similar to this:

```
[
    {"name":"ID","index":"ID"},
    {"name":"Customer Name","index":"Customer_Name","width":275},
    {"name":"State","index":"State","width":125},
]
```

When I try to filter on the "Customer Name" column, the url the grid uses to call back to the server is the orginal url ie something like this

```
?_search=false&nd=1307032133353&rows=25&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc
```

Filtering on the other fields work fine. If I change my colmodel to this:

```
[
    {"name":"ID","index":"ID"},
    {"name":"Customer_Name","index":"Customer_Name","width":275},
    {"name":"State","index":"State","width":125},
]
```

all the fields work fine. Is this expected behaviour? Any known work arounds?

PS. It is doing thing with both vs 3.8 and 4.0 of the grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blank is not allowed character. You can not use it inside of `name` property of the column definition. You should use only the characters allowed for [valid CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). Read more about jQuery restrictions [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).